# Widget layout from Activity still appear after fragment add transaction

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have a problem with fragments. I add fragments dynamically without removing old fragments so they can be recalled when I return. But when I applied the following snippet I found that some of the views that came from the activity did not disappear, such as the Button, TextView, and so on. The results I get are overlapping views

MainActivity.Java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements BlankFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener {

    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    private Unbinder unbinder;

    private FragmentManager fragmentManager;

    @BindView(R.id.dynamic_fragment_frame)
    FrameLayout frameLayout;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_reading);

        unbinder = ButterKnife.bind(this);

        fragmentManager = this.getSupportFragmentManager();
    }

    public void openFragment(View view) {

        BlankFragment fragment = BlankFragment.newInstance("Test 1");
        FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        transaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.enter_from_right, R.anim.exit_to_right, R.anim.enter_from_right, R.anim.exit_to_right);
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        transaction.add(R.id.dynamic_fragment_frame, fragment, "BLACK_FRAGMENT");
        transaction.commit();

    }

     @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        unbinder.unbind();
        super.onDestroy();
    }


    @Override
    public void onFragmentInteraction(String text) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onFragmentInteraction: " + text);
        onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

activity_reading.xml

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#00d9ff"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/dynamic_fragment_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title_read_news"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Ini Judul"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:onClick="openFragment"
        android:text="Open"
        android:stateListAnimator="@null"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

BlankFragment.java

```
public class BlankFragment extends Fragment {

    private static final String ARG_TEXT = "TEXT";

    private Unbinder unbinder;

    private String mParam1;

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    @BindView(R.id.tv_blank_fragment)
    TextView tvTitle;

    @BindView(R.id.back_btn)
    Button backBtn;

    @BindView(R.id.next_btn)
    Button nextBtn;

    private FragmentManager fragmentManager;

    public BlankFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    public static BlankFragment newInstance(String param1) {
        BlankFragment fragment = new BlankFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_TEXT, param1);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_TEXT);
        }

        fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank, container, false);
    }


    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        unbinder = ButterKnife.bind(this, view);

        tvTitle.setText(mParam1);
        backBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String test = "test dari fragment";
                sendBack(test);
            }
        });

        nextBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


            }
        });

    }
    public void sendBack(String sendback) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onFragmentInteraction(sendback);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }
    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        void onFragmentInteraction(String text);
    }
}
```

fragment_blank.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#cfcf1d"
    tools:context=".BlankFragment">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_blank_fragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="@string/hello_blank_fragment" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/next_btn"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/back_btn"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:text="Create new Fragment" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/back_btn"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="back" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Everything went smoothly but the result of my `Mainactivity` layout still appeared on fragment. Please help me
Result as shows as below:
[here 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3EFFW.png)
[here 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jllaX.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In activity_reading, the fragment container view (dynamic_fragment_frame) is declared first, so the button and the text view will be displayed on top of it. If you move the fragment container to the bottom, the fragments will be displayed correctly, so the layout should look something like this:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#00d9ff"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title_read_news"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Ini Judul"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:onClick="openFragment"
    android:text="Open"
    android:stateListAnimator="@null"/>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/dynamic_fragment_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Also you might want to give background color to Fragments. Another thing is if fragment does not have click listener, but button in Activity has click listener, you can still click Activity button from Fragment.

Answer (score 1):

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#00d9ff"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/dynamic_fragment_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title_read_news"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Ini Judul"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:onClick="openFragment"
        android:text="Open"
        android:stateListAnimator="@null"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

With the above layout, Imagine that the `TextView` and `Button` are over the `FragmeLayout`. So when you add a `Fragment` to the `FrameLayout`, the `TextView` and `Button` are still over the `FragmeLayout`. To hide these views, you should use `TextView.setVisibility(View.GONE)` and `Button.setVisibility(View.GONE)` when adding a `Fragment`